# Making a formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Hi I have a maths problem and I can't get the answer, I am 13 years old so bear with me

I have to make a formula with this data:

(Time, Price)

(2,18) (4,17) (6,15) (8,12) (10,8)

I have to make a simple formula to calculate the time if given the price

Comment: What have you tried.

Comment: hint: what is the change in price at each step?

Comment: -1 -2 -3 -4 etc..

Comment: like every step of 2 it does -X + 1

Comment: Please add your attempts to your post (instead of commenting).

Comment: I didn't try anything that is worth saying

Answer (score 2):

The differences between successive prices are $-1,-2,-3,-4,\cdots$ and the pattern is obvious. It is linear.

Now consider a linear polynomial such as $an+b$: the successive differences are $a(n+1)+b-(an+b)=a$, which is a constant, not what we need.

If we move to a quadratic polynomial, let $an^2+bn+c$, the differences are $a(n+1)^2+b(n+1)+c-(an^2+bn+c)=2an+a+b$, and they do vary linearly.

So we can adjust to match $2an+a+b$ to $-n$ (assuming that we start from $n=1$) and identify

$$2a=-1,a+b=0$$

and finally

$$T=2n,\\P=18-\frac{n^2-n}2$$

or

$$P=18-\frac{T^2}8+\frac T4.$$

---

We are only halfway, as we need the time as a function of price.

We rewrite the equation as

$$T^2-2T+8P-144=0$$
or

$$T^2-2T+1=(T-1)^2=145-8P.$$

From this

$$T=\sqrt{145-8P}+1.$$

[image]

---

Checks:

$$\sqrt{145-8\cdot18}+1=2,$$
$$\sqrt{145-8\cdot12}+1=8.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
The price decreased in a pattern of triangular numbers
The time increased in a pattern of even numbers

Comment: I don't get it ? can you make a example

Comment: Do you know what triangular numbers are? If you don't know, search it up on Wikipedia first, and then you can ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: i did i know what it is but i just need the formula

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you. If you want to continue asking on this site, I suggest you put some effort in and read through [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). If not, you are welcome to ask elsewhere.

Comment: If you just need the formula without any working, type your question up on Wolfram Alpha (quadratic passing through (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) ... ), though I imagine your teacher won't be too pleased when they ask where you got the formula from.

Comment: he doest mind he agrees what i am doing

Comment: At least can you tell us your level? The function is a quadratic, so would you be comfortable solving a system of three equations, which involve substituting the points $(2,18), (4,17), (6,15)$ into $ax^2+bx+c$ and solving for the values of $a,b,c$?

Comment: I agree, Toby. Do some research first before asking question.